# Angular Incorrect Margin-Left Applied To Sidenav Content

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have an Angular project using Angular Material but I'm running into a bug where sometimes the `mat-sidenav-content` has a `margin-left: 365px;` applied to it that causes a large white space between the sidenav and the main content.

[image]

[image]

It happens about 50% of the time when I load the app, the `margin-left` is applied.  The rest of the time it is fine.  **However**, if I click the menu button to hide the menu and show it again, then it is fixed until I reload the app.

I feel like it might have something to do with my `isMobile()` function and race condition, but not sure.

In my `app.component.html`

```
<div class="app-container">
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
        <mat-toolbar-row>
            ...
        </mat-toolbar-row>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <mat-sidenav-container class="mat-container" >
        <mat-sidenav #sidenav class="mat-sidenav" [opened]="!isMobile()" [mode]="isMobile() ? 'over': 'side'" style="background: rgb(30, 136, 229);">
            <mat-nav-list class="mat-nav-list" role="list" style="padding-top: 0px;border-top-width: thin;border-top: white;border-top-style: solid;">
                ...
            </mat-nav-list>
        </mat-sidenav>

        <!--The magin-left is being applied here-->
        <mat-sidenav-content>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </mat-sidenav-content>

    </mat-sidenav-container>

    <mat-toolbar style="padding: 0px;background: #e9ecef;">
        <mat-toolbar-row>
            ...
        </mat-toolbar-row>
    </mat-toolbar>
</div>
```

In my app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    private mediaMatcher: MediaQueryList = matchMedia(`(max-width: ${SMALL_WIDTH_BREAKPOINT}px)`);

    @ViewChild('sidenav') public sidenav: MatSidenav;

    constructor(zone: NgZone) {
        this.mediaMatcher.addListener(mql => zone.run(() => this.mediaMatcher = mql));
    }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.sidenav.open();
    }

    isMobile(): boolean{
        return this.mediaMatcher.matches;
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Inside `ngAfterViewInit()` I get the `this.sidenav._width`, sometimes it is `365` and sometimes it is `167`.

I may have narrowed down my problem a little bit.  Inside my `mat-nav-list` I have a

```
<sidenav-group [icon]="'local_atm'" [label]="'Deposits'" [currentRoute]="currentRoute"
                            (changeRouteOutput)="changeRoute($event, false)">
</sidenav-group>
```

It only happens when I have this component.

```
<a class="mat-list-item" mat-list-item="" role="listitem" (click)="toggleBody()"  style="color: white;">
    <div class="mat-list-item-content" style="display: flex; flex: 1; padding-left: 0px;">
        <div class="mat-list-item-ripple mat-ripple"></div>
        <div class="mat-list-text"></div>
        <mat-icon mat-list-icon>{{icon}}</mat-icon>
        {{label}}
        <span class="example-spacer"></span>
        <i class="material-icons" *ngIf="!displayBody">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
        <i class="material-icons" *ngIf="displayBody">keyboard_arrow_up</i>
    </div>
</a>

<div *ngIf="displayBody">
    <!-- Search -->
    <sidenav-element [icon]="'search'" [label]="'Search'" [route] ="'deposit/search'" [currentRoute]="currentRoute"
                    (changeRouteOutput)="changeRoute($event)">
    </sidenav-element>

    <!-- Cheque -->
    <sidenav-element [label]="'Cheque'" [route] ="'deposit/cheque'" [currentRoute]="currentRoute"
                    (changeRouteOutput)="changeRoute($event)">
    </sidenav-element>

    <!-- Pre-Authorization -->
    <sidenav-element  [label]="'Pre-Authorization'" [route] ="'deposit/pre-auth'" [currentRoute]="currentRoute"
        (changeRouteOutput)="changeRoute($event, false)">
    </sidenav-element>
</div>
```

I can add as many `sidenav-element` and it still works fine, only when I have `sidenav-group`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like I found the issue.  Inside `sidenav-group` I had

```
<i class="material-icons" *ngIf="!displayBody">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
<i class="material-icons" *ngIf="displayBody">keyboard_arrow_up</i>
```

When I should have

```
<mat-icon mat-list-icon *ngIf="!displayBody">keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
<mat-icon mat-list-icon *ngIf="displayBody">keyboard_arrow_up</mat-icon>
```

For some reason the `<i>` would sometimes insert extra space.

Answer (score 31):

use autosize

```
<mat-sidenav-container autosize>
<mat-sidenav-container>
```

Answer (score 4):

I have similar problem that was fixed with setting to

```
mat-sidenav-content {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

and

```
mat-sidenav {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

together with `[style.position]="sidenav.opened ? 'initial' : 'absolute'"`
and
flex to `mat-sidenav-container`.

Comment: Setting `mat-sidenav-content` -> `margin-left: 0 !important;` Just makes it stick completely to the left.  It doesn't respond to position of `mat-sidenav`

Comment: @DevEng, we need it since our sidenav width can changed dynamically, so we need to adjust mat-sidenav-content to new width.

Comment: hmm, inside `ngAfterViewInit()` I get `this.sidenav._width`, it is `365px`,  Not sure why it shrinks

Answer (score 2):

This error is due to the icons. After a reload (clear cache) with slow connection, angular will start to render the string with the name of the icon. Since the string is larger than the fully rendered icon, there will be extra space. After a reload, since the icon is already on the device storage, this does not happen.

My solution was to fix the value of the sidebar width inline.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I came up with (using angular's `flex-layout`):

```html
<div fxLayout="column" style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;">
  <mat-toolbar fxFlex="none">
    <div fxFlex="grow">
      <button mat-button (click)="sidenav1.toggle()">toggle nav1</button>
    </div>
    <div fxFlex="none">
      <button mat-button (click)="sidenav2.toggle()">toggle nav2</button>
    </div>
  </mat-toolbar>
  <mat-sidenav-container fxFlex="grow" fxLayout="row">
    <mat-sidenav opened mode="side" #sidenav1 fxFlex="none"
        [style.position]="sidenav1.mode !== 'over' && sidenav1.opened ? 'relative' : 'absolute'"
        style="width: 240px; background-color: red;">
      nav1
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav opened mode="over" position="end" #sidenav2 fxFlex="none"
        [style.position]="sidenav2.mode !== 'over' && sidenav2.opened ? 'relative' : 'absolute'"
        style="width: 240px; background-color: blue;">
      nav2
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content fxFlex="grow" style="background-color: green;">
      content
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

```css
.mat-sidenav-content {
  margin-left: 0 !important;
}
```

Works perfectly on desktop and mobile `:)`

**EDIT: Stackblitz:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r13fve

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious this issue can appear in different situations. But the common part is that they all cause change of calculated width of `mat-sidenav` via CSS.

In my case, `mat-sidenav` had fixed width and `padding: 16px`. `mat-sidenav-content` sometimes was shifted by 32px. My guess is that by default `box-sizing: content-box`. But my reset CSS was changing it to `border-box` for all elements. I fixed it by explicitly applying `border-box` to `mat-sidenav`.

Answer (score 0):

a workaround with setTimeout worked for me

```
export class AppComponent implements  AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('sidenav') 
  private sidenav: MdSidenav;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.sidenav.open();
    }, 250);
  }
}
```

Source:
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/6743#issuecomment-327416089