# Angular 6 - Sidenav overlaps content with ngx-translate

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngx-translate

I'm having some troubles using `ngx-translate`, because translated texts are shown in the selected language **AFTER** the main component is shown.

I have a main component like this:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav [opened]="true">
        <app-menu></app-menu>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

The menu component has a list with translations, like this:

```
<nav>
    <mat-list>
        <mat-list-item>{{ 'app.list.home' | translate }}</mat-list-item>
        <mat-list-item>{{ 'app.list.contact' | translate }}</mat-list-item>
    </mat-list>
</nav>
```

When the page is rendered, the `mat-sidenav-content` has a `margin-left` lower than mat-sidenav width. I assume that it happens because the menu translations where made **AFTER** the `margin-left` was calculated. This causes the `mat-sidenav` overlaps the `mat-sidenav-content`.

I'm pretty new with angular and I don't know if there is a way to fix that, like "calling" the translation somehow before rendering the sidenav or something like that.

Best regards.

Comment: have the same issue. have you fixed it?

Comment: @vato I will post it as answer as soon as I go back to work. Forgot to post it. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, if its the same problem, but I had a similar case, where the size of the navigation changed after init. In my case I had a collapsible sub navigation, that could increase the size to the right. A very easy solution for that was the "autosize" attribute in the `<mat-sidenav-container>`.

```
<mat-sidenav-container style="height: 100%" autosize>
...
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Found the solution here:
https://github.com/crisbeto/material2/blob/8187a0c6896e4e3ea2a6748d90724ac3c880cd60/src/lib/sidenav/sidenav.md#resizing-an-open-sidenav

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by giving mat-nav-list fixed width.

```
<mat-nav-list style="width: 250px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs an explanation:

The margin of the component is calculated before the text is translated. So the size of the navbar is less than its actual size.

Solution I used:

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
  // margin are calculated before translation gives the final size for the sidenav
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
}
```

This helped:
[Angular Incorrect Margin-Left Applied To Sidenav Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49176479/angular-incorrect-margin-left-applied-to-sidenav-content)

Don't forget:

```
implements AfterViewChecked
```