# Material sidenav margin issue

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

I'm a backend developer helping someone with an Angular webapplication and I ran into an issue when adding the fonts of our company, he uses material.

[image: redsidenav, yellow margin, blue container]

The red part is a `mat-sidenav` block and the blue is `mat-sidenav-content` the yellow part is some margin that suddenly is that big when I changed the fonts.

In devtools it looks like this:

[image: devtools]

so there is somewhere an element.style setting the margin but can't seem to find it in the code. Now the strange thing is if I dragged the tab out of chrome as a seperate window the issue is resolved but I don't think users will like doing that. Any clue why the margin changes and how I can resolve this permanently?

[image: resolved]
[image: devtools of resolved issue]

```css
/* VAriables */ 
:root {
  --color-accent:   black; /* Fallback */
}

.u-category-test     { --color-accent: rgba(67, 119, 64, 0.5); }
.u-category-qa       { --color-accent: rgba(153, 100, 19, 0.5); }
.u-category-prod     { --color-accent: rgba(216, 3, 3, 0.5); }

/* Nav */

  .nav-header {
    position: relative;
    padding: 2rem;
  }
  
  .nav-title {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .nav-title strong {
    font-weight: 600;
  }
  
  .nav-header-icon {
    position: absolute;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    top: 1.5rem; /* magic */
    right: 1.75rem; /* magic */
  }
  
  .nav-item {
    padding: .5em 0.5em 0.5em 0;
  }
  
  .nav-icon {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: .25rem;
  }
  
  .nav-category {
    margin: .2em 0;
    padding-left: 2rem;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  
  .nav-button {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: .2rem;
    padding-left: calc(2rem + 16px + .5rem); /* padding + icon + magic */
    line-height: 2;
    text-align: left;
    font: inherit;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: inherit;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: default;
    outline: none;
  }
  .nav-button:hover,
  .nav-button:focus:not(.is-selected) {
    background-color: hsla(0,0%,0%,.1);
  }
  .nav-button.is-selected {
    background-color: var(--color-accent);
  }

  .nav-button.is-selected,
  .nav-button.is-selected em {
    color: #fff;
  }
  .nav-button.is-selected:focus {
    opacity: .8;
  }
  
  .nav-button em {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    pointer-events: none; /* makes it invisible to clicks */
  }

  .nav-footer {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    padding: 2rem;
    border-top: 1px solid var(--color-border);
    text-align: center;
  }

  .nav-footer-version {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: .75rem;
    line-height: 2;
    text-align: left;
    font: inherit;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: inherit;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: default;
    outline: none;
    text-align: center;
  }

  #button-download {
    background-color: rgba(196, 196, 196, 0.5);
  }
  #button-download:hover {
    background-color: rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.5);
  }
  .client-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #eee;
  }

  .main {
    height: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<header class="nav-header">
  <h1 class="nav-title">Clients</h1>
</header>

<div class="nav-item">
  <h5 class="nav-category">
    <span class="nav-icon flag-icon flag-icon-be"></span>
    Client
  </h5>
  <button type="button" class="u-category-test nav-button" id="button-test" routerLink="test" routerLinkActive="is-selected">Dev</button>
  <button type="button" class="u-category-qa nav-button" id="button-qa" routerLink="qa" routerLinkActive="is-selected">QA</button>
  <button type="button" class="u-category-prod nav-button" id="button-prod" routerLink="prod" routerLinkActive="is-selected">Production</button>
</div>
```

```css
.client-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #eee;
  }

  .main {
    height: 100%;
  }
   @font-face {
    font-family: 'Custom';
    src: url('/assets/fonts/Custom.ttf') format('truetype');
  }

  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  html {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Custom', 'BlinkMacSystemFont', 'Lucida Grande', 'Segoe UI', Ubuntu, Cantarell, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    overflow: hidden; /* Prevents rubber-band scrolling of the whole "page" */
    color: var(--color);
    background-color: #fff; /* To cover OSes with no default background color */
  }

  body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  h1,
  h2,
  h3 {
    margin-top: 0;
    line-height: 1.5;
  }
  
  h1 {
    font-family: 'Custom';
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
  
  h2 {
    font-family: 'Custom';
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  
  h3, h4 {
    font-family: 'Custom';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  
  h5{
    font-family: 'Custom';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 30px;
  }

  table {
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 1px solid hsla(0,0%,0%,.08);
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
  }
  th {
    background-color: hsla(0,0%,50%,.06);
  }
  th,
  td {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid hsla(0,0%,0%,.08);
    border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
  }
  
  div.main{
    padding: 30px;
    button{
      font-family: 'Custom';
      margin: 10px;
    }
    button:hover{
      background-color: transparent;
      color:black;
    }
  }
```

```html
<mat-sidenav-container class="client-container">
  <mat-sidenav mode="side" opened><app-side-nav></app-side-nav></mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <div class="main mat-app-background">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: The `margin-left` on your `mat-sidenav-container` is set by Angular Material according your `mat-sidenav` width. I guess your font changes the width of something in your sidenav. Could you post the css code of your sidenav. Do you set the width of your sidenav explicitly? (You probably should)

Comment: The width isn't set in the side nav, I'll try that. Btw how can I cleanly paste alot of css here?

Comment: Paste the code in the editor, highlight the code, click the `code sample` button. Also post your html.

Comment: added a dumbed down version of the nav

Comment: Please include your `mat-sidenav-container`, `mat-sidenav` and `mat-sidenav-content` html and css. You obviously don't have to include the whole sidenav content but include any sidenav content wrapper you have.

Comment: Alright added more from app.component and the styless.scss

Comment: Thanks. So have you tried it with a fixed `width` for the `sidenav`? Tell me if that fixes the problem or not.

Answer (score 1):

What helped me was applying `position: unset` to `mat-sidenav-container`. This element by default has `position: relative`.

Interestingly I had this problem only with multiple sidenavs.

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav mode="side" position="start" opened>
    <desktop-main-navigation></desktop-main-navigation>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
  <mat-sidenav mode="over" position="end">
    Notifications
  </mat-sidenav>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Your specific issue and fact it happened when adding fonts might has been explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56219106/2804285